# How can I import resnet_rs module from keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to import resnet_rs module from keras. But counldn't find a way to do it via keras.applications. Using tensorflow 2.8

I tried the following:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet_rs import ResNetRS50
```

Got no module error.

Then I tried to use it via api, again got error

```
tf.keras.applications.resnet_rs.ResNetRS50(
    include_top=True,
    weights='imagenet',
    classes=1000,
    input_shape=None,
    input_tensor=None,
    pooling=None,
    classifier_activation='softmax',
    include_preprocessing=True
)
```

So, how can I import resnet_rs? (as we do for other resnet import) Any suggestions or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Tensorflow are you on? I was on Tensorflow 2.8.2 and it wasn't working for me either. I switched to 2.9.1, and it fixed the import. I think those modules were added only recently. That's why previous versions won't work.

To upgrade to the latest version:

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

Comment: It is fixed now. Thanks a lot!  Gosh, I almost had it with these version things. Now something else gonna break, off to new bugs :)

Comment: previously my version was 2.8.2. using via google colab. After I have upgraded to TensorFlow 2.9.1. it's working